# How to make poetry use dependencies which are under development?

Tags: python, python-poetry

The short summary is: How can we get poetry to use a package under development for downstream builds?

Suppose you have a Python package which you are developing and you'd like to build a dependent of the current development version using the current development version. So, e.g., `A` is your package under development, package `B` depends on `A`, and `B` has something like this in its `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
A = ">=1.2.3"
```

The constraint for `A` is unbounded above, so if the development version of `A` is newer than 1.2.3 and poetry can find the package for `A`, then `poetry lock` and `poetry install` should be able to handle getting the intended development version of `A`. It looks like `poetry publish` can publish to a devpi server, so ensuring that poetry can find the development package also seems solved.

The obstacle I'm seeing is how to *version* the development builds which are published to devpi. SemVer, as used by Poetry, is a linear order; it supports build metatada following the x.y.z, but the build metadata doesn't affect the sort order, so any 1.2.4 development builds would all be considered equal for satisfying the example constraint. The development builds won't be linearly ordered---there could be builds from different branches in git, for example, which simply aren't comparable. If I push `A-1.2.4-f909c2d3` to our local pypi repo and someone else pushes `A-1.2.4-ca24040d`, I want my build to use the one I pushed and the other developer will want their build to use the one they pushed...

How can I tell downstream builds how to find the right development version?

I'd like a solution that doesn't involve manually modifying all of the downstream `pyproject.toml` files.